# Equality concerning a certain complex integration

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

I would like to verify the following statement. However, I do not know what should I do. Generally, I think that, since there is \$1/2\pi i$ part, Winding number, Residue theorem and Argument Principle might be helpful. But the condition required in those theorem does not exactly meet the given condition of this problem. :

Suppose that $f$ is holomorphic in neighborhood of the closure of the unit disc. If $|z| \leq 1$, we have $$f(z)(1- |z|^2) = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{|w| = 1} \frac{1 -\bar zw }{w-z}f(w)\ dw.$$

Comment: Currently, I think that I can prove the case when $|z| < 1$ using Residue theorem. However, I think that there might be something wrong since I think that the the equality should not hold for $|z| = 1$. Actually, I think that it is impossible to verify the statement for $|z| = 1$ since $$\frac{1 - \bar z w}{w-z}$$ might not be well-defined since $w-z =0$ for some $w_0 = z$. Is mu thought correct ? Is the problem should be for $|z| < 1$ only ?

Answer (score 0):

For a circle $C$ centered on the origin of radius $r$ and a function $f$ holomorphic on and within $C$, we have Cauchy's Integral Formula for $z$ in the interior of $C$:

$$ f(z) = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_C \frac{f(w)}{w-z}dw$$

Already at this point we recognise the first half of the desired expression.

Now consider the function $ g(z) = z f(z)$; $g$ is holomorphic everywhere $f$ is, so we may use Cauchy's Integral Formula again:

$$ zf(z) = g(z) = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_C \frac{g(w)}{w-z}dw = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_C \frac{wf(w)}{w-z}dw$$

So

$$f(z) = \frac{1}{2\pi i z} \int_C \frac{wf(w)}{w-z}dw = \frac{1}{2\pi i |z|^2} \int_C \frac{\bar zwf(w)}{w-z}dw $$

And the desired expression follows. This is true for $|z| < 1$.

All that remains is to show that the expression holds for $|z| = 1$. Under this assumption, $f(z)(1 - |z|^2) = 0$, so it suffices to show the right hand side vanishes also. Consider the following:

$$\begin{align} 
\frac{1}{\bar z} \int_{|w| = 1} \frac{1 -\bar zw }{w-z}f(w)\ dw & = \int_{|w| = 1} \frac{1 -\bar zw }{\bar zw-\bar zz}f(w)\ dw \\ &  = \int_{|w| = 1} \frac{1 -\bar zw }{\bar zw-1}f(w)\ dw \\ & = -\int_{|w| = 1} f(w) dw = 0 , \, \text{by Cauchy's Theorem}
\end{align}$$

So since $\bar z$ is non-zero, the expression holds for all $z$ on and within the unit disc.

Comment: If $|z| =1$, then $z$ is on the unit circle. So there exist $w_0$ with $|w_0| = 1$ such that $w_0 = z$. So for any $|w| = 1$, I think that $$\frac{1 - \bar z w}{w-z}$$ is not well-defined. This is because $w - z = 0$ when $w = w_0$. So I am not sure if you can multiply $\frac{1}{\bar z}$ to the integral since the integrand is already brown up to infinity at $w = w_0$. If I misunderstand something, please clarify the point.

Comment: Note that integrals don't necessarily have to have bounded integrands to converge. Consider for example $$\int_0^1 \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}} dx $$

If it helps, you could start from Cauchy's theorem and work backwards to construct your integral using the method shown.